# how to exports multiple nested functions to the other files so i can reuse the code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying export a module with `module.exports` from nested functions and I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help with this code?

This is `module.js`

```
const mainF = ()=> {
    const secondF = (a,b)=> {
        console.log(a+b)
    }
    secondF();
}
mainF();
module.exports = [mainF,secondF]
```

and this is `main.js`

```
const {mainF,secondF} = require('./module.js');
secondF(5,5)
```

It gives an error: `secondF` is not defined. I want to print the output that is `10`

Comment: Why do you think you want to do that? What end goal are you trying to serve by doing it?

Comment: `const` are block scoped.  The definition of `secondF` is not scoped high enough to allow for the export as you are wanting to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define `secondF` outside of the `mainF` function.

```js
const secondF = (a,b)=> {
    console.log(a+b)
}

const mainF = ()=> {
    secondF(); // this will log: NaN
}

mainF();
module.exports = [mainF,secondF]
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i import this in main.js because it gives error when i try my approch.

Comment: @Amar - You're using object destructuring. Since you're exporting an array, you'd use array destructuring: `const [mainF,secondF] = require('./module.js');`. But consider exporting an object with named properties instead, that's the normal thing to do (and then your version using object destructuring would work.)

Comment: it give Nan and 10 as an output can you please tell me how can i get the output 10 only .

Comment: It returns `NAN` because you call `mainF()` which calls `secondF` without any parameters .. `mainF` doesnt do anything useful so remove it

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to do that. Every time `mainF` is called, a **new** `secondF` is created. So although you **could** do this:

```
// DON'T DO THIS
module.exports = [];
const mainF = ()=> {
    const secondF = (a,b)=> {
        console.log(a+b)
    }
    if (module.exports.length === 1) {
        module.exports.push(secondF);
    }
    secondF();
}
module.exports.push(mainF);
mainF();
```

...**don't**, because only the first `secondF` would be exported, not all the other ones created by calling `mainF` the second, third, fourth, etc. times.

It's hard to tell you what to do instead because you haven't said what your end goal is. Typically, you only export top-level functions, not nested ones.